# ImageCache not working in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

For some reason the [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) module doesn't work.

Drupal just doesn't generate the ImageCache subfolders and image files.

The user www-data is the owner of the folder imagecache, I also have set 777 permissions, just to be sure that it is not an issue.

The point is that ImageCache was working on the previous server. Is maybe a server configuration issue?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should have something to do with programming (i.e. writing code). For general administration issues, try [Pro Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled the ImageAPI GD2 module? Imagecache wont work without it (unless you're using imagemagick). Also look at your drupal status report (`/admin/reports/status`) and recent log messages (`/admin/reports/dblog`
) -- any recent errors/setup issues related to Imagecache may be mentioned there.

Comment: ok I've installed imagemagick now and configured properly. The Report says it is the selected toolkit. However the images are still not generated any idea ?

Comment: any messages in the drupal log?

Comment: no, no logs messages. I was now googling and I came with another question: is maybe because clean urls are not enabled ?